# Storing dictionaries into Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, nsdictionary

I have a Firebase instance where I want to store a dictionary of values I want to store into firebase. I have looked on the documentation https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html as a reference but can't seem to get it to work. The following is my attempt:

```
    //Declared above are the currentUser values as so:
    var currentUserFirstName: String!
    var currentUserLastName: String!
    var currentUserObjectID: String!

    var attendeesArray = ["objectID": currentUserObjectID, "name": currentUserFirstName + " " + currentUserLastName]
    var eventRefChild = EventReference.childByAutoId()
    eventRefChild.setValue([
        "eventName":eventName.text,
        "attendees": attendeesArray,
        "eventCreator": currentUserFirstName 
        ])
```

But I keep getting an error saying: `Could not find an overload for '+' that accepts the supplied arguments` when I try to do `eventRefChild.setValue([...` and I'm honestly not too sure why I am getting this issue. Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: The variable `EventReference` is assigned as so: `EventReference = Firebase(url:"<Insert Firebase URL>")`

And inside `currentUserFirstName` and `currentUserLastName` are an individual's first and last name grabbed from `Facebook` so it would look something like `Bob` `Smith` respectively.

Comment: Do this let name = currentUserFirstName + " " + currentUserLastName. then use the name constant.

Comment: I'm not sure why you closed your previous question on the exact same problem, but my comment remains the same: the only `+` operator in this code is where you are concatenating `currentUserFirstName + " " + currentUserLastName`. If you step through the code, does that line execute correctly?

Comment: Can you provide the more code? It will be useful to see the values of currentUserFirst and currentUserLast. Firebase will accept a dictionary for setValue so there shouldn't be a problem there. Also I'm not sure what EventReference is. If you could provide more information on that, it would be helpful.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that line executes correctly when we step through the code. I have gotten that portion of the code to store correctly into my database.

Comment: What happens if you simply hardcode the values: `Firebase(url:"<Insert Firebase URL>").childByAutoId().setValue([ "eventName":"Google I/O", "attendees": ["objectID": "209103", "name": "Frank van Puffelen"]])`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I get an error saying: `Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions` when I hardcode the values of the `attendees` array. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is the comma after attendeesArray in the setValue statement extraneous?

Comment: @Jay oh yes, sorry. I removed that and I still got the same issue.

Comment: Immediately before the var attendeesArray = statement, can you define the three vars as such: currentUserFirstName = "Test" currentUserLastName = "User" currentUserObjectID = "objectID". Then right after the var attendeesArray statement add a print(attendeesArray). Does it get to the print statement?

Comment: @Jay I am able to print out the `attendeesArray` statement. It prints as so: Attendees Array: [objectID: objectID, name: Test User]. However, to get it to compile, I had to change the contents of `attendees` attribute in the `Firebase.setValue` statement to a string like "test." Printing the array works however if that's what you're looking at.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The issue is the values that are being loaded into

```
var currentUserFirstName: String!
var currentUserLastName: String!
```

As a test, I created a sample project with the following code, which is a duplicate of your posted code but with normal strings loaded into the var's:

```
    var myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://myproject.firebaseIO.com/")

    var currentUserFirstName = "Test"
    var currentUserLastName = "User"
    var currentUserObjectID = "object ID"

    var attendeesArray = ["objectID": currentUserObjectID, "name": currentUserFirstName + " " + currentUserLastName]
    var eventRefChild = myRootRef.childByAutoId()
    eventRefChild.setValue([
        "eventName": "eventName",
        "attendees": attendeesArray
        ])
```

the project compiled and runs correctly and the expected data is written to Firebase. Note that the eventName.text was replaced with a string as well but that doesn't affect the answer.

The investigation needs to turn to what's loaded in the var's, and the answer is that one of those var's, currentUserFirstName or currentUserLastName is being loaded with an OBJECT (class), not a string.

As a side note, why are the var's declared as implicitly unwrapped optionals (the !)

edit: adding additional info to deal with the optionals

```
if let actualString = currentUserFirstName {
    println(actualString) //proceed working with the the optional string
}
else {
    return // something bad happened! currentUserFirstName does not contain a string
}
```

To prevent code from errors when an optional contains no value, add the above code directly above the concatenation line of code. What happens here is the we are assigning the string in currentUserFirstName (optional var) to a actual string (a standard, non-optional var).

If the expression evaluates to true then we can proceed evaluating currentUserFirstName.

If it's false, then currentUserFirstName does not contain a string so handle the error elegantly.

Comment: I am using the variables declared as unwrapped optionals because I am using the values and passing them between segues. I will try to play around with this and let you know.

Comment: Update: what I tried was to declare the variables like so: `var currentUserFirstName: String`, `var currentUserLastName: String`, `var currentUserObjectID: String` but I get an error saying `'_' not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'`

Comment: It seems like you're right. The declaration of the variable as type `String` is affecting my ability to store values into Firebase. Anyway around this? I still want to pass these values between segues and store them into my Firebase reference.

Comment: I don't think declaring the var as String is the issue. When you are declaring it as a Implicitly Unwrapped Optional  (String!), there is no guarantee the var contains a reference to a string, and in those cases a runtime error is generated. My guess is that the var is being overwritten, set to nil, or becoming undefined elsewhere in code. You should probably evaluate those two strings before concatenating them.

Comment: Hm, but even if I declare the var as an optional (as String?) or without an optional or implicitly unwrapping it (as String), I still get the same issue as I posted above where `'_' not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'`. I have double checked if the variable is being overwritten, set to nil and I have ensured that they are set as they should be. I tried setting just `currentUserFirstName` to Firebase as another attribute and that has worked for me.

Comment: I edited my original answer and where I have added the attribute `"eventCreator": currentUserFirstName` is where I am getting the error `'_' not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'`

Comment: Please see my updated answer above for an idea of how to deal with optionals that don't contain an expected value. I am pretty sure your optional var, currentUserFirstName or currentUserLastName is being stuffed with an object or possibly nil. In my testing, any time an optional is assigned something other than a string results in the same error you are experiencing.